# Why maximize failed to find max value

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Given $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{2}{c}<1,a,b,c>0,a,b,c\in \mathbb Z$, find the maximize of $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{2}{c}$

```
Maximize[{1/a + 1/b + 2/c, 1/a + 1/b + 2/c < 1, 0 < a, 0 < b, 0 < c, 
Element[{a, b, c}, Integers]}, {a, b, c}]
```

This doesn't return answer.

But when I change to [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).

```
Select[Table[{a, b, c, 1/a + 1/b + 2/c}, {a, 1, 100}, {b, a, 100}, {c,1, 100}] // Flatten[#, 2] &, Last@# < 1 
&] // MaximalBy[#, Last] &
```

$$4,13,3,\frac{155}{156}$$

So why [`Maximize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Maximize.html) fail to do it ?

Comment: @Artes That's what I also thought first. But notice that the maximization is taken only over the positive integers, so there should be a maximum...

Comment: @Artes , here is a simple version: $x>0,x\in \mathbb Z, \frac 1x<1$ , what's the maximize of $\frac 1x$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

The equivalent to your `Table` -- although **very much slower** -- using `Maximize` would be

```
Maximize[{1/a + 1/b + 2/c, 1/a + 1/b + 2/c < 1, 0 < a <= 100, a <= b <= 100, 
    0 < c <= 100, Element[{a, b, c}, Integers]}, {a, b, c}] // 
  AbsoluteTiming // Quiet

(* {215.532, {155/156, {a -> 4, b -> 13, c -> 3}}} *)
```

or

```
Maximize[{1/a + 1/b + 2/c, 1/a + 1/b + 2/c < 1, 0 < a <= 100, a <= b <= 100, 
    0 < c <= 100}, {a, b, c}, Integers] // AbsoluteTiming // Quiet

(* {210.86, {155/156, {a -> 4, b -> 13, c -> 3}}} *)
```